# Deserialize JSON into C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm pretty new to C# and JSON deserialization.
I'm making a request to a website and I'd like to store the data into my SQL database using C#.
I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json library.

Here is an example of the object I'd like to deserialize:

```
{
  "test": [],
  "result": {
    "inside": {
      "MMLEHH-YUR": {
        "id": null,
        "number": 0,
        "alt": "ok",
        "descr": {
          "price": "4.33000",
          "price2": "0",
          "state": "none"
        },
        "vol": "12",
        "misc": ""
      },
      "OZWVHR-N3ED4-CM3ACG": {
        "id": null,
        "number": 0,
        "alt": "ok",
        "descr": {
          "price": "5.34000",
          "price2": "0",
          "state": "none"
        },
        "vol": "1443",
        "misc": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result of:

```
using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
{
    jsonResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
}
```

Then I do:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonResponse);
```

but after that I'm completely lost to build the structure to add it into my SQL database.

What I'm looking for is a result like this:

```
Global = "MMLEHH-YUR"
Id = null
Number = 0
alt = "ok"
price = 4.33
price2 = 0
state = "none"
vol = 12
misc = ""
```

and so I could add everything into my SQL database.

Does anyone have an idea?
So far I did:

```
sAlt = json.result.inside.????.alt;
```

but I can't seem to pass through and enter the "MMLEHH-YUR"

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` instead of a c# data model?  If you'r eventually going to put it into a SQL database it would seem to be easier to deserialize into some sort of fixed schema.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that, like i said i'm pretty new on c# and json, i've played a while ago with the dynamic but not others. Do you have any exemple that can fit my purpose ? :)

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, by the way: `descr":`

Comment: Also you might want to try parsing your JSON object into an `JObject`.

Comment: Please look at https://json2csharp.com/ or https://quicktype.io/csharp, these sites will help you create model classes that will make deserialization much easier, and strongly typed (which is infinitely better than using the no-rules-do-whatever-you-want-and-good-luck-with-that `dynamic`).